Unable to deploy solana programs on devnet
after deploy on localnet successful,
run solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com
and config Anchor.toml
[programs.devnet]
counter = "58MKv4J4uWugtVvxfN2zgoVvUWAXUNLx8Qw9GQbnY4i3"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

Try many times, but still failed with this:
thread 'main' panicked at cli/src/program.rs:2809:26:
Should return a valid tpu client: PubsubError(ConnectionError(Io(Os { code: 104, kind: ConnectionReset, message: "Connection reset by peer" })))

I just tried deploy and it worked using anchor deploy on devnet. I use solana 1.18.17 and anchor 0.30.1. What are your versions?
